# How to hide or show all desktop icons from the command line

Tags: windows-10, command-line, desktop-icons

Without a reboot. There's a way to do this from the UI, but I'd like to be able to do this automatically.

Essentially - how do I toggle this checkbox from the command line:

[image]

I would like to change this check value during a script such there is a clean desktop background while certain commands are running, and then return them later:

```
  echo "There are icons visible on the desktop"
  hideIcons.bat
  echo "Now they're all gone!"
  showIcons.bat
  echo "Yay they're back"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: nirsoft's nircmd can do this I believe. `Hide the desktop window` -> `nircmd.exe win hide class progman` and `Show the desktop window (After hiding it in previous example)` -> `nircmd.exe win show class progman`.

Comment: @LPChip nice! that's workable and will help. Was hoping to do it without changing the desktop picture, but can live with it if that's the best we can do.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the little program of
[HideDesktopIcons](https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/gg/HideDesktopIcons.zip).

This tiny program will hide or show the desktop icons, where each call reverses
the last action.

VirusTotal pronounced it as clean from viruses.

For more details see the article
[Create a Shortcut to Toggle the Desktop Icons](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-a-shortcut-or-hotkey-to-turn-the-desktop-icons-on-or-off/).

Comment: Yeah ok - a custom tool for it is the best winner so far. +1. Pity there's no source. I'll hang on a bit hoping for a no-exe answer.

Comment: Confirming the virusTotal result. https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/ffb0cdb9c7fa8f9700a18be4f2633eb3f76f70355d7a06898fb62544ce624840/details